# PayPal embedded flow: Payment can't be completed. This feature is currently unavailable

Tags: paypal, embedding

I'm trying to get the example shown here to work:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-embeddedPayment-curl-etc/

However, I always get the error `Payment can't be completed. This feature is currently unavailable.`

This is the code, taken directly from PayPal's documentation (where `{{PAY-KEY}}` is a pay key you obtain from PayPal):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/apdg.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay" target="PPDGFrame" class="standard">
            <label for="buy">Buy Now:</label>
            <input type="image" id="submitBtn" value="Pay with PayPal" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif">
            <input id="type" type="hidden" name="expType" value="mini">
            <input id="paykey" type="hidden" name="paykey" value="{{PAY-KEY}}">
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        var dgFlowMini = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlowMini({trigger: 'submitBtn'});
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

The same error occurs when you try to use this for Preapproval (`[...]/flow/preapproval`, request variable `preapprovalKey`), and also with the LightBox code sample.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: https://www.paypal-notify.com/eventnotification/search?eventSearchType=PayPalSiteStatus does not say anything about maintenance going on at the time of testing.

Comment: can you use embedded flow to request a preapproval key instead of payKey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contacted PayPal support and they apparently fixed it (again...).

Comment: I have an Android and iOS native app that runs Adaptive Payments in a webview.  It works but it's the standard html that isn't mobile friendly.  I want to use Embedded Payment Flow but before converting I want to make sure it's compatible with mobile webviews, did you get this to work?  Was it on Android or iOS?

Comment: No, this wasn't for mobile. But shouldn't take too much effort to adapt the sample code to mobile for testing.

Comment: Thanks, there are a lot of mixed answers about if this can work or not on mobile webviews.